# Unable to connect to MongoDB’s Atlas using Heroku during production

Tags: node.js, heroku, production

Beginner question so here goes nothing:

Atlas’ URI works normal locally, connects right away. Once I push it to Heroku, it won’t connect.

Also getting the error: NODE_ENV value of “production” did not match any deployment config file names

I’ve tried multiple ways of holding my URI value, including .env files, in plain-site, and currently using a config/default.json importing into my server file.

Can someone guide me to what I am missing?

```
const db = config.get('mongoURI')

mongoose
    .connect(db, {useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then( () =>{
        console.log('MongoDB connected via Mongoose')
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.log('error message: ' + err)
    })
```

Comment: can you show the code where you connect mongo? maybe repo if it is not private

Comment: Edited. Like stated, works locally, won't get deployed

Comment: are using config package and do you have defaultçjson and production.json or just default.json?

Comment: I don't think I'm using a config package. When using the dotenv method, I imported using 'require('dotenv').config' and stored keys in .env file. when using the config.get() method, I only have a default.json file, not prod.json

Answer (score 0):

You should get the environment variables via `process.env.YOUR_VAR` rather than config.get, you can look at the [dotenv markdown](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) for more information

Also when deploying project to Heroku, if you don't add .env file to your git repository, then you need to give the environmental variables from Config Vars tab like [here in the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)